# Is it possible to track cross origin redirection?

Tags: http, url-redirection, content-security-policy, iframe

I can successfully iframe a page on origin B from origin A (no x-frame-deny, content security policy, etc). A page on origin B (page X) redirects to a page on origin C (page Y) with a server side redirect (status 301). Origin C doesn't allow iframes.

Is it possible to track which page is redirected to (page Y) from origin A. I can iframe page X (origin B) from origin A which will automatically trigger the redirect to page Y on origin A in the iframe. The iframe won't load but I'm wondering if there's a way to grab the URL it's trying to load.

Using iframes or another other way (popups, fetch, etc).

Comment: Welcome to the community. If I understood your question correctly you could use JS for that

Comment: @SirMuffington Yes. Javascript or anything else in the browser.